# What is the com.android.email/cache folder?

Tags: stock-email-app

I am looking at where data is stored on an Android device.  The ending of the path is com.androidemail/cache/then a jpg.  What is the email cache?

Answer (score 1):

[Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) is a kind of temporary storage for faster access to e.g. files loaded via network. In case of an email app, this most likely holds contents that where attached to a mail (like images: you even named a `.jpg`, that's it), so it doesn't need to be re-loaded via the network each time the user looks up a message (see: [Web cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_cache)).

Also see our [cache](/questions/tagged/cache) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/cache/info).